# removeAllObjects for NSMutableArray that populates UITableView crashes with ARC

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a property of

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *timesArray;
```

It is used to populate the data in my UITableView.  When I want to clear my view, I do this:

```
- (void)clearView {
    self.nameField.text = @"";
    self.noteField.text = @"";
    if ([_timesArray count] > 0) {
        [self.timesArray removeAllObjects];
        [self.customTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

The removeAllObjects causes a crash.  I am not sure why.  I looked around and a lot of posts talk about an object being overreleased.  How is that happening if I'm using ARC and not calling retain/release on any objects.  My _timesArray just holds NSDate objects I get from a UIDatePicker.

My stack trace looks like:

[image]

My insertPill looks like:

```
- (void)insertPill:(id)sender {
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:InsertPillNotification object:self];

    [self clearView];
}
```

If I don't removeAllObjects, and just do:

```
NSMutableArray *emptyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
self.timesArray = emptyArray;
```

This works.  But I'd still like to know why by removing the objects it does not work.

Edit: I initialize the array in viewDidLoad:

```
_timesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
```

When I want to add a new object to the array, I do this:

```
NSMutableArray *tempUnsortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_timesArray];        
        [tempUnsortedArray addObject:_datePicker.date];
        self.timesArray = tempUnsortedArray;
```

I'm not sure if the way I'm adding data the array is causing the issue or not.

Comment: Did you override the setter for timesArray?

Comment: What happens if you don't call the getter, and just do [_timesArray removeAllObjects]?

Comment: @mprivat No I dod not override the setter for timesArray.

Comment: @Joel if I do [_timesArray removeAllObjects], I get the same thing.

Comment: Probably you are starting with an NSArray. insted of just passing and retaining it, Make a mutableCopy

Comment: When you add an object to the array you should just use `[self.timesArray addObject: _datePicker.date]`. However, the way you are doing it should not be the cause of this problem.

Comment: @ThomasW has you on the right track. That's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` exception. This probably means that the object you think is a `NSMutableArray` is not really one. It is probably an `NSArray`. Where are you assigning the object?

To start debugging the issue, `po` the object before calling `removeAllObjects`. What type of object is it reported as?

Otherwise it could be possible that there is a non `NSObject` element in `timesArray`.

Comment: I po _timesArray and got: `(NSMutableArray *) $2 = 0x06a207b0 <__NSArrayI 0x6a207b0>(
2012-05-07 03:36:02 +0000
)`.  I initialize the object in viewDidLoad.

Comment: `__NSArrayI` appears to be the internal class name for `NSArray`. If the object was a mutable array it would be `__NSArrayM`. Somewhere you are setting `_timesArray` to a non-mutable array. Look at all the places where `_timesArray` is getting set.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *timesArray;
if ([_timesArray count] > 0)
```

It seems, you syntesize your property like this:

```
@syntesize timesArray = _timesArray;
```

You chacking count of `_timesArray`, but removing object from `timesArray`. I never set new name for my properties and don't sure how it works, but I dont like it.